# Capital letters in application menubar in WP

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I have to display terms "Apple" and "Grapes" in application menubar of my Windows Phone application. My XAML looks as below:

```
        <AppBar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems> 
            <AppBar:BindableApplicationBarMenuItem 
            Text="Apple" 
                Command="{Binding AppBarMenuClickedCommand}"
            IsEnabled="True" >
            </AppBar:BindableApplicationBarMenuItem>
        </AppBar:BindableApplicationBar.MenuItems>
```

But, even though I am giving the words as mentioned above, on the emulator/device, it appears as "apple" and "grapes". But, after opening an image in Pictures application, it displays "share on SkyDrive". So, it seems possible, but doesn't happen by default. Is there a way to display A and G in capital letters in my case. Please advice.

Comment: I guess its not possible

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Wonder how it is achieved in Picture application. Is it because it is an in-built application?

Comment: Pictures label is all small letters on my WP7.5 device.

Comment: yup that application is built in native sdk

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible - texts in application menu bar are displayed lowercase by design as mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/261c653b-a3d7-41d7-8d73-6114da2aa805/why-menuitems-in-application-bar-always-lower-case)

> It is part of the Metro design. Hard coding the text to upper case
>   results in the text being displayed in all lower case unless the
>   language calls for the word to be upper case.  i.e. German nouns must
>   be capitalized, so the first letter of a word can remain in upper
>   case.